# eclipse git revert/reset option not found

Tags: eclipse, git, git-reset, git-revert

How can revert/reset a file using the eclipse egit (team) plugin?

I'm opening the team menu but can't find any reset/revert option. See screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Look at the `Replace With` menu option.

Comment: @AleksandrM - it's an answer - not just a comment :)

Comment: Oh, and it worked of course, though not asking for confirmation :( I guess eclipse counts on the user knowing about the local history feature...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in EGit's "History" view:

[image]